# I want to prevent my player to blink/teleport in a surface within a collider in Unity2D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm making a topdown 2D game in Unity2D, and i want to implement a teleport/blink when i press the space bar, later it will have a cooldown etc..

But in order to do that i need to prevent the player to teleport in walls for example.

To do so I tried several things, but I can't make it work I'm pretty new and can't find tutorial on what I need.

I was thinking about checking with my mouse position if, when i click space bar, i'm hovering an GameObject with the non walkable tag on.

I tried mostly to do it with raycast2D but can't figure out the proper syntax and way to do it.

I paste my code here but this is yet another iteration of something i'm starting to think is maybe not the best way to do it.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
```

public class PlayerSpells : MonoBehaviour
{

```
void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetButtonDown("Jump"))
    {
        Vector3 aimingAt = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
        var rayHit = Physics2D.GetRayIntersection(aimingAt);

        if (!rayHit.collider) return;

        if (hitInfo.collider.gameObject.tag == "wall")
        {
            Debug.Log(rayHit.collider.gameObject.tag);
            Debug.Log("You can't blink here");
        }
        else
        {
            StartCoroutine(Blink());
        }
    }
}

IEnumerator Blink()
{
    Debug.Log("Blinking");
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(1);
    Debug.Log("Has Blinked");
    
}
```

}

Thanks for anyone willing to help, if you need more information let me know i will respond as quick as possible !

Thanks again and have a good day/evening !

Editing my post

I've managed to make this to work :

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class Teleport : MonoBehaviour
{
public LayerMask obstacleLayer; // The layer(s) to consider as obstacles
public Image fillImage; // Reference to the Image component with Sprite Shape Fill
public float teleportCooldown; // Cooldown period in seconds

private Camera mainCamera; // Reference to the main camera
private float lastTeleportTime; // Time when the last teleportation occurred

private void Start()
{
    mainCamera = Camera.main;
    lastTeleportTime = -teleportCooldown; // Initialize to allow the first teleport immediately
}

private void Update()
{
    UpdateCooldownFill();

    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space) && CanTeleport())
    {
        TeleportToMousePosition();
    }
}

private void UpdateCooldownFill()
{
    float cooldownProgress = Mathf.Clamp01(1 - (Time.time - lastTeleportTime) / teleportCooldown);
    fillImage.fillAmount = cooldownProgress;
}

private bool CanTeleport()
{
    return Time.time - lastTeleportTime >= teleportCooldown;
}

private void TeleportToMousePosition()
{
    Vector3 mousePosition = Input.mousePosition;
    mousePosition.z = -mainCamera.transform.position.z; // Set the z-coordinate based on camera distance
    Vector3 worldPosition = mainCamera.ScreenToWorldPoint(mousePosition);

    Vector2 direction = (worldPosition - transform.position).normalized;
    float teleportDistance = Vector3.Distance(transform.position, worldPosition);

    RaycastHit2D[] hits = Physics2D.RaycastAll(transform.position, direction, teleportDistance, obstacleLayer);

    if (hits.Length == 0) // No obstacles hit, safe to teleport
    {
        transform.position = new Vector3(worldPosition.x, worldPosition.y, transform.position.z);
        lastTeleportTime = Time.time; // Update the last teleport time
    }
    else
    {
        foreach (RaycastHit2D hit in hits)
        {
            if (!hit.collider.isTrigger) // Ignore trigger colliders
            {
                Vector2 adjustedPosition = hit.point - direction * 0.1f;
                transform.position = new Vector3(adjustedPosition.x, adjustedPosition.y, transform.position.z);
                lastTeleportTime = Time.time; // Update the last teleport time
                break; // Teleport only once to the adjusted position
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

But i'm stopping at the first wall i encounter even if i try to teleport in a legit place but behind an obstacle.

For the moment this is ok with me i'm working on other features and will come back on the teleport later.

Thanks for the help !

Comment: ScreenToWorldPoint requires a z parameter to work.  Instead use ScreenPointToRay.

Answer (score 0):

> `if (hitInfo.collider.gameObject.tag == "wall")`

You've defined the variable as `rayHit`, so use the following syntax:
`if (rayHit.collider.gameObject.tag == "wall")`